# How do Formtastic decides which table column is used in the `select` options to represent the row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, formtastic

When you do the following:

```
form.input :users
```

And the attribute `#users` represents a has_many relationship, then Formtastic generates a `select` field with the user #id and #name, but...

How do Formtastic decides that the #name column is what has to be used?

Why not #email, or #login? Is possible to specify it without having to create the collection manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found my answer, the source comments for the :select tag says the following:

> The way on which Formtastic renders the `value` attribute and content
>   of each `<option>` tag is customisable through the `:member_label` and
>   `:member_value` options. When not provided, we fall back to a list of
>   methods to try on each object such as `:to_label`, `:name` and
>   `:to_s`, which are defined in the configurations
>   `collection_label_methods` and `collection_value_methods`.

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb